# Group SUM field by formula in REPORT FOOTER section does not work

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-formulas

My `SUM` of a field result in `REPORT FOOTER` section by grouping in formula does not work. In the following pictures you can see the flow. What am I doing wrong? Regards.

**Picture 1.**

[image]

**Picture 2.**

[image: Grand Total Report Footer]

**Picture 3.**

[image]

Comment: A Summary field may be too simple for what you are trying to achieve.  I would suggest you try this with a Running Total Field instead.  This would allow you to set a formula on the Evaluate condition of your Running Total where you can use the formula `{sp_rptInternal;1.Tax_Rate_Percentage} = 10.00` rather than using Select Expert to filter the report.  This may not fix your immediate problem, but when you also need to calculate the sum for 20% tax rates you can create a second Running Total Field with a modified formula to allow both figures in the report.

Comment: But what will be the physical location of my summary field? That is the main problem! I want to move it where I want. I don't need it in the group section. I need it like in this picture: https://imgur.com/a/39SdZfI @R.McMillan

Comment: Summary Fields and Running Total Fields need to be in Footer sections by design.  Crystal Reports generates reports in a way that using them in sections before the footers creates problems with the scope of the data being summarized.  You should be able to have the layout in your image by designing that bottom grid in the last, or outer-most, group level's footer section.

Comment: But I can I do something like this: Local numbervar Z; if sp_rptInternal;1.Tax_Rate_Percentage} = 10.00
then Z = Sum ({sp_rptInternal;1.Sell_Price})

Comment: Yes, Local and Shared variables can be used anywhere in your report.  They can be very effective when Summary and Running Total fields do not fit your needs.

Comment: Yes, but I am not getting the result, that is the problem. I would appreciate if you have an example. If you answer on a seperate answer field and its working, you have my up vote. @R.McMillan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178092/discussion-between-r-mcmillan-and-ferid-sejdovic).